# robotframework execute python method against result

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robotframework with Jython. I don't have access to requests module therefore I would like to use native urllib2 to test the respose code of a URL.

So, I am doing something like this

```
*** Settings ***
Library urllib2

*** Test Cases ***

Test HTTP
   ${result}=   urlopen   http://localhost:80
```

It seems to work but this returns a filehandle. I would like to read the file handle.

Having another python script is out of the question since this is an embedded system.

So, is there a way to evaluate ${result}

Comment: How do you want to evaluate it?

Comment: want to make sure I don't get a 404. I realized I can do ${result.getcode()} which will give me the code. But if its 404 it gives me an exception.